# Show only post of custom category

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have a custom post types called photo gallery. In that post type I have registered a taxonomy called video. Then i have created two category under video called 'personal' & 'commercial'. Now i want to show only the commercial category post to a page section. How can I do that? Here is the code I have tried but not working

```
                      <?php 

                            $args = array(
                        'post_type'=>'photo_gallerys',
                        'post_status'=>'publish',
                        'video'=>'commercial',
                        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
                        'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')
                         );
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

       <?php the_title(); ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code hope you'll find your solution

```
    <?php
    $tax_post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'your post type name',
            'posts_per_page' => 999,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'your taxonomy name',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => your category id
                )
            )
        );

$tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($tax_post_args);

    while($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
           $tax_post_qry->the_post();
           the_title();
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

if you want to get posts from category slug then use this code in tax_query array

```
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => 'your category slug'
```

Answer (score 0):

use `'cat' => "your_cat_id` in your wp query argument.

for example if I want to display post for only commercial category and commercial  have `category id 21`, then I will write query to display post like this:

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
'post_type'=>'photo_gallerys',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'video'=>'commercial',
'cat' => 21,
'posts_per_page'=>-1,
'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')
 );
```